# Showing Different Dialog with shared code in Android

Tags: android, menu, dialog

I have done some coding and designed XMLs previously and now I am adding two activities in my project, but when I run my app, it shows the dialog in different theme and menus also in different theme in previously developed activities and currently developed activities. I am using the same code for putting the dialog and menus in both sections of code[image]

In the Image I described both menu and dialog. Now I want to make both dialog and menu look like older style but in a single activity it comes like new ones.

**How can make them look like they are in other activities?**

I cannot figure out how two different styles are coming in a single project

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I have copy and past the code from old to new one bothe codes are same

Comment: There may be case where you have different theme for activities.

Comment: how can i change theme? for activies

Comment: You should compare style.xml and in manifest for your previous activity where dialog is showing and in new activity where new dialog is showing, there must be different theme in both.

Comment: I got it thanks @Kinnar Vasa